# What to put in Spark SetPageBaseType setting

Tags: c#, console-application, spark-view-engine

I use Spark to output some HTML straight from a console app. I have the following view classes in my project.

```
//A shared view that all other views should use
public abstract class SharedView : AbstractSparkView
{
    public string BasePath = string.Empty;
}

public abstract class ApplicationView : SharedView
{
    public Application Application { get; set; }
}
```

I then have the following setting for Spark

```
var settings = new SparkSettings()
            .SetPageBaseType(typeof(ApplicationView )) //What should go in here!?
            .AddNamespace("SomeNameSpaces")
            ;
```

I now keep getting a CompilerException when I *not* put the ApplicationView as the SetPageBaseType - *shouldn't I have my shared base view there*?

I try to use the same engine instance to write several different views to disk (with diffrent view models) and I then have to set up a engine instance for each one with diffrent SetPageBaseType (for the current view I'm rendering)- should that be so?

Bascially I need help with above and a general explanation of SetPageBaseType and how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the PageBaseType per view by changing the setting directly off the engine's Setting property.

```
engine.Settings.PageBaseType = typeof(ApplicationView).FullName;
```

I wrote a simple wrapper for this process awhile back... you can find it [here](http://www.randomdevnotes.com/2010/01/using-the-spark-view-engine-in-a-desktop-application/) if you are interested.

Comment: Excellent. Just what I needed.